# Brownian Motion

Tags: physics

trying desperately to prepare a short animation of the inside of a cell. I want to show little proteins bouncing around inside the membrane. I have 3 problems, I will post all 3 separately because it seems those are the rules. I've also uploaded the blender session below.

problem #2: is there any way to introduce Brownian motion to my particles?   I want them to float around randomly a little bit.  Only thing I can think of is increasing bounciness so high that it appears to keep moving, but after about 20 frames it all stops moving.

[image]

https://www.mediafire.com/file/upw5904htbfry0s/Phospholipids_and_brownian_motion.blend/file

Comment: please first read you answers and update your file/screenshots accordingly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you turn off gravity, you can add a turbululence force field like this:

[image]

Give it some strength (like 200) and bigger noise amount.

So you get something like this:

[image]

Play around with the values to get a feeling what they do.

You can also animate this values or even animate the movement of your force field.

[image]

Comment: phenomenal.  it worked. thank you!

Comment: Pls click the checkmark left of my answer, if it helped. Thanks.

Comment: sorry, forgot.  done!